# Select from three tables without where or on clauses

Tags: mysql

I have three tables from which I want to show some information. Problem is that one of them `ps_mycase_output_design` isn't connect by anything with others. 
All I want is just to be able to show information from all of them. I don't need to query by ID's ,.. or WHERE clauses etc. This is from where I started but I've got

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY mycase.key_product_output DESC LIMIT 10' at line 13
```

Here is the simple query

```
SELECT customer.*, mycase.*, orders.*

FROM
    ps_customer customer
LEFT JOIN 
    ps_orders orders
LEFT JOIN
 ps_mycase_output_design mycase 
ORDER BY mycase.key_product_output DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Your left joins need an `on` clause that defines on which columns you join

Comment: you are forgetting ON clause

Comment: I don't want to use ON.. I just want to select them

Comment: Well but that is not how JOINs work. Add example data and expected output to see what you are up to

Comment: thats not possible, You have to use ON when there are joins

Comment: This is not how programming works. Program need to parse your query syntax. `JOIN` must have the `ON` keyword. If you do not want to use, do not programming.

Comment: Anyway, can I ask why do you not want to use the correct syntax with `ON`?

Comment: Wow @karacsi_maci great advice ... really great .. `if I don't want to use I should not programming`?!

Comment: Because they can't be connected via `ON` clause

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. These tables are related to each other? Does Chaos Legion answers helps you?

Comment: @karacsi_maci please read the question again! Yes, Chaos Legion answer is what I need.

Comment: @karacsi_maci Some joins do not require an `on` clause, such as join, inner join, or cross join (they all mean the same in MySQL).

Comment: You may not get the result you want, but ON is not required

Comment: As I already said I just want to query them. From there I can manipulate and show results. Case is closed. Thank's for the help and karacsi's advice to quit programming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use ON or WHERE clause, try this:

```
SELECT customer.*, mycase.*, orders.*
FROM
    ps_customer customer,ps_orders orders,ps_mycase_output_design mycase 
ORDER BY mycase.key_product_output DESC LIMIT 10
```

Not sure this is what you need logically.

Comment: Thank's. Yes, this is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` or `inner join` without `on` clause (or even comma separated list of table names) to create a Cartesian join (every record from table A is joined to every record from table B). I prefer to use `join` without `on` because joins and commas have different operator precedence:

```
SELECT customer.*, mycase.*, orders.*

FROM
    ps_customer customer
JOIN 
    ps_orders orders
JOIN
 ps_mycase_output_design mycase 
ORDER BY mycase.key_product_output DESC LIMIT 10
```

However, I believe that between customers and orders table there should be a connection. Since you have not indicated anything about such connection, I did not include an `on` clause.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I've implemented Chaos Legion answer already.